# Climbing Stairs DP Problem base case concept

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

**Question:**
You are climbing a staircase. It takes n steps to reach the top.
Each time you can either jump 1 or 2 or 3 steps. In how many total number of ways can you jump to the top?

**My Explanation:**
Well I'm thinking of applying recursion because I can find the solution by solving similar subproblems and on that process, there will be many overlapping subproblems so I'll array data structure to save the denomination of similar subproblems so that I don't need to solve same subproblem twice. So I'm using top down DP approach.

**My Doubt:**

Now to build the solution, I need a base case where the program flow ends and it returns back to it's parent node(if you visualize it as a tree). So the base case what I was thinking is like when I was at the floor, at ground 0 so there will be no other ways I can reach ground 0 state, so it's the base case.

**When **n=0**, I should return 0 or 1, that's my doubt? Well I have written the code, so the code work when I return 1, not 0 at n=0. So why I should return 1 when n=0, what's the reason behind it? Please Help!!!**

**My Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int climbing_ladders_topDown(int n, int k, int dp[]){
    //Base Case
    if(n==0){
        return 1;
    }

    //LookUp
    if(dp[n]!=0){
        return dp[n];
    }

    //Recursive Case
    int total_num_of_ways = 0;
    for(int jumps=1;jumps<=k;jumps++){
        if(n-jumps>=0){
            total_num_of_ways += climbing_ladders_topDown(n-jumps,k,dp);
        }
    }
    
    dp[n] = total_num_of_ways;
    return dp[n];
}

int main() {
    int num_of_stairs = 4;
    int num_of_jumbs = 3;
    int dp_arr[100] = {0};

    cout<<climbing_ladders_topDown(num_of_stairs,num_of_jumbs,dp_arr);
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:** 7

**Correct flow of Code (thanks to @appleapple):**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int climbing_ladders_topDown(int n, int k, int dp[]){

    //Base Case
    if(n==0){
        return 0;
    }

    //LookUp
    if(dp[n]!=0){
        return dp[n];
    }

    //Recursive Case
    int total_num_of_ways = 0;

    for(int jumps=1;jumps<=k;jumps++){
        
        if(n-jumps > 0){
            total_num_of_ways += climbing_ladders_topDown(n-jumps,k,dp);
        }
        
        if(n-jumps == 0){ // have reach the end or ground 0, base so no more move possible in downward direction
            total_num_of_ways += 1; 
        }
        
        if(n-jumps < 0){ //we can't move to -ve state/underground, because it doesn't exist
            total_num_of_ways += 0;
        }

    }
    
    dp[n] = total_num_of_ways;
    
    return dp[n];
}

int main() {

    int num_of_stairs = 4;
    int num_of_jumbs = 3;
    
    int dp_arr[100] = {0};

    cout<<climbing_ladders_topDown(num_of_stairs,num_of_jumbs,dp_arr);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: because `total_num_of_ways += climbing_ladders_topDown(n-jumps,k,dp);` need it to be `1`.

Comment: well that's a logical answer because that's what I have figured it out by trial n error. But I wanna know, the reason why at n=0, dp[0] = 1?

Comment: yes `dp[0]` should be 0. so your algorithm strictly speaking is wrong (for `n=0`, it output `1`)

Comment: I am sorry, I edited it.

Comment: just a note, `dp[0]` *can* be `1`, if you consider *no move* as a possible way. (while `0` means it need to *make at least 1 move*)

Comment: When you say the word 'no move', no move-up or no move-down?

Comment: no move means take no action, or, if we output all the actions taken to reach goal, it would be empty collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you request it to be `1` here (`f(0) = 1`)

```cpp
for(int jumps=1;jumps<=k;jumps++){
   if(n-jumps>=0){
      total_num_of_ways += climbing_ladders_topDown(n-jumps,k,dp); // here
   }
}
```

---

if you want `f(0)=0`, since recurse into `f(0)` doesn't really make sense anymore (there is no possible solution, just like `f(-1)`)

the algorithm for such case would becomes

```
if(n<=0){ // not really necessary as implied inside the loop
   return 0; // not possible
}
///...
int total_num_of_ways = 0;
for(int jumps=1;jumps<=k;jumps++){
   if(n-jumps>0){
      total_num_of_ways += climbing_ladders_topDown(n-jumps,k,dp);
   }
   if(n-jumps==0){ // have reach the end, no more move possible
      ++total_num_of_ways; // you put this under n=0
   }
   // if(n-jumps<0){/*do nothing*/}
}
```

---

Note: `f(0) = 0` or `f(0) = 1` provide a little different meaning. (so the algorithm also change)

- `f(0) = 1` means *no move* is a possible solution.
- `f(0) = 0` means *at least 1 move* need to be taken.
- Both imply there is no possible way to go back once leave `0` (no negative movement), btw.

Comment: if at n=0, return 0 then the whole output will be 0

Comment: @codosopher no, because the loop are not same.

Comment: if you run the same code by returning 0 at n=0, you can see, what I'm talking about

Comment: @codosopher it definitely not 0? what are you talking about? https://wandbox.org/permlink/lzl79V9oaWuJcH7h

Comment: oh because you add that extra iffy condition if(n-jumps==0) at the end. But, what's that actually mean, can you kindly tell in laymen language

Comment: and why did you add it

Comment: @codosopher because you cannot move `0` step (you **already** reach the end after `jumps`), so there is simply 1 possible move (logically there is no reason to move after you already at the end, too).

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238612/discussion-between-codosopher-and-apple-apple

Comment: [++total_num_of_ways] or [total_num_of_ways++], will do the same thing in here, right? but meaning is different...

Comment: @codosopher yes they're same here.

Comment: Yesterday I give a thought of it and in my philosophy, I see it like f(i) gives the number of ways you can reach i'th state from ground floor, which is 0. So, f(0) = 0, because you're in the base and no way you can reach to ground 0 unless there is hell you're coming from which present underground (being sarcastic)

Comment: Now, thanks for your help and a little bit improvement in my code, I was able to aligned with my own philosophy to understand the program flow vividly now. Therefore, when we have reached the base/ground floor through recursion from top to down - so now to reach any state from ground floor is 1, because f(0) = 0 so there is only 1 way we can reach state 1 or 2 or 3 (in question, total jumps possible = 3 so) and that's the reason, when we hit the base condition in our logic, (n-jumps == 0) we did increment in total number of ways by 1, (total_num_of_ways +=1).

Comment: and when you jumps up from hell/underground to reach ground 0, the condition would be like if( n-jumps < 0 ) so we just do nothing but ( total_num_of_ways += 0 ) because there is no hell/underground.

Comment: @codosopher thanks for sharing your thought :) just a note for your edit on question (not in comment), `if(n==0)` is not the base condition there. (and actually not necessary)

Comment: yeah, you're right. It's not necessary. I run the code without the base case, it worked. So what I do now...you know, my top-down DP approach, I always follows a fixed template, you know what I mean like inside the recursive function, first [base case], second [LookUp DP Table], third [Recursive Case/Recurrence Relation] and fourth [update DP Table & return answer]. Because, it's topDown DP Approach so it's always be [Recursion + Memoization] that's why, I always like that template to solve any DP problem with TopDown Approach.

Comment: so if I omit/remove the base case as you have said, it's not necessary now...I feel terrible and also feel like it's morally wrong act of doing, solving DP problems using topDown Approach without base case. Even bottomUp DP Approach also needed base case. Just sharing my thought, what I feel inside. :D Hope, you'll understand :)

Comment: @codosopher the base case just moved to different position (inside the loop). [Here is what it may looks like when it's outside](https://wandbox.org/permlink/p4Rdtp2BBKclhrRL), maybe you fell better for it :)

Comment: yeah I checked it and I also tried to omit the base case, it gives segmentation fault. But what's the different between my edited code and your code, looks same except one if case missing

Comment: @codosopher well not sure what your edited code is. but if it cause segment fault, you probably has base condition `n==0` instead of `n<=0`

Answer (score 1):

In these kind of problems of counting number of ways, `dp[0][..]` is usually equal to `1`, as there're 1 way to jump 0 step, doing nothing.

And with your problem, as you already figure out this is a DP problem, it can be solve easily with a `for` loop, resembling similarities to the Tribonacci sequence (https://oeis.org/A000073) with different base cases starting point:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int maxn = 1e3;

int main()
{
    int n; cin >> n;
    int dp[maxn+1];

    //base case
    dp[0] = 1; dp[1] = 1; dp[2] = 2;

    //dp
    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++)
    {
        dp[i] = dp[i-1] + dp[i-2] + dp[i-3];
    }

    cout << dp[n];
}
```

Test:

```
Input : 3
Output : 4
```

Explanation : There're 4 ways : 1 + 1 + 1, 1 + 2, 2 + 1, 3.

Your way of recursion and remembering DP state isn't wrong, it's just a lot more chunky.

To be clear, setting `dp[0] = 1` as a base case is just an easy and (kind of) conventional thing. You could totally do the base cases as `dp[1] = 1, dp[2] = 2, dp[3] = 4` and start from `dp[4]`.

The complexity of the code is `O(n)`, but if you need bigger `n` value, check out this post : https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/solving-linear-recurrence-relation/

Comment: well I wanna know the reason, why dp[0] = 1, not 0 when n=0...I think, it's not a conventional thing, it may vary depends on problems

Comment: @codosopher  Base case means the most trivial case of the function that you are trying to compute. As the function here is `dp[i] = dp[i-1] + dp[i-2] + dp[i-3]`, we need to declare the first 3 base cases.

And obviously it depends on the function, but more so it depends on what you choose as a base case.

Here, `dp[0]` answers the question : How many ways can we jump 0 steps.

Comment: that's true. That's why, it all comes down to base case and what it returns

Comment: @codosopher Yes, it's just that `dp[0] = 1` is a bit illogical when you first see it. And you could always start from different point, such as `dp[1]` or `dp[10]`. It's just what you define as *base* in a particular case. For example, I give you the sequence `10, 15, 20, 25,...` with the function `f[i] = f[i-1]+5`. To answer the question why I choose `10` as a base, it's just that I define `10` as the base case, there's no particular reason or logic in this case.